# How to validate in a .net WebAPI a string value with only 3 possible values?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, data-annotations

I know the question seems easy, but I wanted to know if there a better way than do

if (partner.Type =="value" Or value2 or value3)

Maybe with Data annotations?

this is my entity POCO

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Partner Entity
    /// </summary>
    [SharedCosmosCollection("shared")]
    public class Partner : ISharedCosmosEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Partner id
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner name
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner contact name
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerContact { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner contact phone
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerPhone { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner contact Office 365 domain
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerDomain { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner type, silver, gold or platinum
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner start date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner end date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parter enabled
        /// </summary>
        public bool  Enabled { get; set; }

        [CosmosPartitionKey]
        public string CosmosEntityName { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddPartner([FromBody]Partner partner)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            try
            {
                var partnerStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStorePartner;
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                var added = await partnerStore.AddAsync(partner);
                return Ok(added);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could define an `enum` with the values that you expect and then use `Enum.TryParse` to check whether the value is valid.

Comment: that means the partnetype on the entity will still be string, istead of the enum type, right?

Comment: How exactly you would implement that is up to you. If you don't want to change the entity's property type you can always use converters to map between `string` and `enum`.

Comment: thats exactly my question,whats the best approach, so that I dont need to do that business logic validation in the web api method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression Validator as a Data Annotation on your property.

```
[RegularExpression("^silver$|^gold$|^platinum$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
public string PartnerType { get; set; }
```

P.S. Regular Expression may need tweaking as I only typed it on the top of my head to match the possible values you mentioned.

Comment: nice solution :)